# In TSDoc how do I document an object?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use TSDoc on a project, but I can't figure out how to document an object

```
  /**
   * 
   * @param param0.maxConcurrent - Document this individually
   * @param param0.retry - Document this individually too
   */
  constructor({
    maxConcurrent = Infinity,
  }:
```